# Did Sanjaya take part in Mahabharata war

Tags: mahabharata

In [Drona Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07091.htm#fr_137)/Jayadhrata vadha parva, Sanjaya says:

> I myself, with my own troops, cased in mail and equipped with weapons, and supported by four hundred foremost of bowmen, resisted Chekitana.

Ganguly's footnote for this also says:

> This Sloka occurs in all the texts. It would seem, therefore, that Sanjaya was not always a witness only of the battle for narrating what he saw to Dhritarashtra, but sometimes at least he took part in the battle.

Are there any other references where Sanjaya did actively take part in the war and was not only a spectator?

Answer (score 1):

Sanjaya did take part in the war. In Shalya parva, when Duryodana disappeared from battle field, he [says:][1]

> I myself, O king, having only two kinds of forces, and becoming reckless of life, joined the five leaders of our army, and fought with the forces of the Pancala prince, posting our men on that spot where Saradwat's son was stationed. We had been afflicted with the shafts of Kiritin. Nevertheless, a fierce battle took place between us and the division of Dhrishtadyumna. At last, vanquished by the latter, all of us retreated from that encounter.

[1] https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09025.htm